# IMU shows continuous slow spin around z axis

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trouble shooting this problem and I thought maybe someone else had seen it. I have an 9250 IMU installed, callibrated and launched through an IMU node. When I display the TFs in RVIZ they look right. When I move the robot around in the air, they seem to be right. But when I place the robot stationary on a table, the z-axis is slowly spinning around. Any immediate thought on where my problem might be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400217/imu-shows-continuous-slow-spin-around-z-axis/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2022-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's called 'drift' and it's quite standard for IMUs to have, especially one as inexpensive as the one you're using.

Usually the way to solve this is to do some sort of sensor fusion between multiple sensors. That way you can (partly) compensate for the drift.

More expensive IMUs have less drift, but that's more often than not some sort of software in the IMU that tries to filter out the noise.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1